# How to avoid using exec inside of Laravel Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I wrote a working Artisan command that takes two parameters: `name` and `import`. It then creates a MySQL database with the name `name` and imports into it with the `import` sql dump.

**MySQLCreate.php**

```
exec("mysql -u homestead -psecret -e \"create database " 
. $this->argument('name') . "\"");

exec("mysql -u homestead -psecret " . $this->argument('name') 
. "<" . $this->argument('import'));
```

This works but I am sure there is a better way to achieve this. I'm concerned with hardcoding the password into an `exec` command and am pretty sure using `exec` inside of a Laravel app is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Laravel itself doesn't provide a tool to execute a command, it is bundled withy **Symfony's** **Process** component that makes it very easy. It also allows for asynchronous process execution as well as reading process output in real time.

In order to execute external command, you need to do:

```
$command = "mysql -u homestead -psecret " . $this->argument('name') . "<" . $this->argument('import');
$process = new Process($command);
$process->run();
```

You could also utilise **ProcessBuilder** to make creating the **Process** object simpler:

```
$builder = new ProcessBuilder();
$builder->setPrefix('mysql');
$builder->->setArguments([
  '-u homestead', 
  '-psecret',
  $this->argument('name')
]);
$builder->setInput(file_get_contents($this->argument('import')));
$builder->getProcess()->run();
```

You can find more details in **Process** component docs here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Just to add, the Process namespace is *Symfony\Component\Process\Process;*